# Find out what Windows domain policies cause certain restrictions on a workstation

Tags: windows-7, windows, group-policy, security-policy

I work within a team of developers in a large bank.

We all have full admin rights on our win7 workstations.

The Windows infrastructure in our company is getting an overhaul, so there seems to be many infra teams making policy changes which effect our workstations.  Some mornings we won't be able to write to C: drive.  Other mornings we can't RDP to other machines.

Each of these policy changes involve painful conversations to many different teams to try and find out who made what change and how it can be reversed.

I would be nice to get a tool which can tell us exactly which policies are currently affecting certain restrictions.  e.g. how to find out what policy setting is stopping us from writing to C: drive.  So that we can more clearly communicate with our infra teams to let them know which policy is affecting us.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps your machines should be relocated to a different OU in the Active Directory, with policy inheritance blocked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run [gpresult](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733160(v=ws.10).aspx) from a command line. and use the `/H` option to create a html format output.

Inspect if you like, and determine which setting and policy you are having problems with.  Submit to your support team as needed.

If your system is so locked down that you can't run gpresults, then your only option is to complain.